# Tool to refactor boolean expressions

Tags: refactoring, boolean-logic, boolean-expression

I'm looking for a tool to refactor boolean expression. I've got expressions like

```
a1 => (b1 <=> c or d) AND 
a2 => (b2 <=> c or d) AND
a2 => (b2 <=> c or d)
```

The tool should be able to simplify expressions, e.g. extract the sub expression "c or d" in the example above. Is there a free computer algebra system which can do this?

Currently I think of refactoring the expressions manually an prove the equivalence with a little haskell quickcheck script.

Comment: Look at [this question and answers](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14902141/57477) - Basically, use [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about a tool but take a look at [Boolean Algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra_(structure))

you can draw a grid of all the inputs and output to try and find a minimal boolean expression

Comment: The first problem is that the number of variables of about 50. The second problem is that I'm not looking for a minimal expression. I want to refactor existing expression to make them maintainable.

Comment: in loo of finding a tool, write some tests around it and create a method a1 >= foo(b1)

Comment: you could loop thru arrays of a and b to trim it down too

Answer (score 1):

The [DMS Software Reengineering Tookit](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/DMSToolkit.html) could do this.

It is generalized compiler technology for parsing languages (including Java) to ASTs and symbol tables.    DMS also provides source-to-source transformations, and associative and commutative law rewriting.

Your boolean expressions would show up as Java AST expression trees.
By providing a set of rules about boolean algebra, you can manipulate
those expression trees.

We have done this in the past to carry out boolean expression simplification and transformation for C, RLL and a system of diagnostic equations, both on large scale expressions, and on lots of medium scale expressions (scale much like your example).

EDIT 5/19/2010: See an [example of conventional algebra transformations](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/SimpleDMSDomainExample.html) using DMS.  Its trivial to construct a variant that does Boolean algebra instead.

Answer (score 1):

[Boolean Refactor and Simplification](https://www.dcode.fr/boolean-expressions-calculator)

This tool worked great for optimising complex boolean expressions.