# Simplify boolean expression i.t.o variable occurrence

Tags: boolean, boolean-logic

How to simplify a given boolean expression with many variables (>10) so that the number of occurrences of each variable is minimized?

In my scenario, the value of a variable has to be considered ephemeral, that is, has to recomputed for each access (while still being static of course). I therefor need to minimize the number of times a variable has to be evaluated before trying to solve the function.

Consider the function

> f(A,B,C,D,E,F) = (ABC)+(ABCD)+(ABEF)

Recursively using the distributive and absorption law one comes up with

> f'(A,B,C,E,F) = AB(C+(EF))

I'm now wondering if there is an algorithm or method to solve this task in minimal runtime.

Using only Quine-McCluskey in the example above gives

> f'(A,B,C,E,F) = (ABEF) + (ABC)

which is not optimal for my case. Is it save to assume that simplifying with QM first and then use algebra like above to reduce further is optimal?

Comment: The Google term is "fanout minimization". There are algorithms to design fanout-free circuits where every literal does not occur more than once. However, this is only possible for special boolean expressions.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try `Logic Friday 1`

It features multi-level design of boolean circuits.

For your example, input and output look as follows:

[image]

Comment: I'm looking for an algorithm or method since i need to implement it into code. The result Z as shown above is not optimal for my case as A and B are evaluated twice

Comment: Look at the circuit depicted in the image. A general algorithm beyond heuristics is not known to me. You might ask Google for "Reduced Binary Decision Diagrams". http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_decision_diagram

Comment: Reading papers on fanout and bdds, this seems to be the general answer I was looking for, thanks.

Comment: @user2722968 If you plan to implement this yourself you want to (at the very least) read chapter 8 in *Synthesis and Optimization of Digital Circuits* by Giovanni De Micheli. The theory of multi-level minimization is far less simple than that of two-level minimization.

Comment: Also chapter 11 in *Logic Synthesis and Verification Algorithms* by Hachtel and Somenzi.

Comment: If you want something more "state of the art" rather than widely used in industry see http://alcom.ee.ntu.edu.tw/publications/iccad07-fd.pdf or http://www.eecs.berkeley.edu/~alanmi/publications/2008/iccad08_lp.pdf 
Multi-level optimization is still an active research area.

Answer (score 1):

I usually use [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28A+and+B+and+C%29+or+%28A+and+B+and+C+and+D%29+or+%28A+and+B+and+E+and+F%29) for this sort of thing.

Answer (score -1):

You can use an online boolean expression calculator like https://www.dcode.fr/boolean-expressions-calculator

You can refer to [Any good boolean expression simplifiers out there?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14902141/any-good-boolean-expression-simplifiers-out-there) it will definitely help.

Comment: I'm looking for an implementation, so an algorithm is being looked for

Comment: then you can go through Karnaugh Map Boolean Algebra Simplification Technique
https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/digital/chpt-8/logic-simplification-karnaugh-maps/
Let me know if it helps