# LDAP - optimising filter

Tags: php, ldap

How can I optimise the following LDAP filter to remove the duplication in the code?

```
(|(&(cn=PATH*)(cn=*2013*)(|(cn=*_S1_*)(cn=*_1_*)))(&(cn=MICR*)(cn=*2013*)(|(cn=*_S1_*)(cn=*_1_*))))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, the single most important thing you can do to optimise is to *make sure the correct indexes are in place* on the LDAP server. This doesn't help simplify an actual filter though... This problem is (almost) simple [boolean expression simplification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14902141/any-good-boolean-expression-simplifiers-out-there).

Firstly, convert from [*LDAP filter prefix notation*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4515#section-3) to *infix notation* (some [example](http://www.cs.man.ac.uk/%7Epjj/cs2121/fix.html) algorithms). I'm using place-holder symbols for the filter items:

```
a  cn=PATH*
b  cn=*2013*
c  cn=*_S1_*
d  cn=*_1_*
e  cn=MICR*
```

So this prefix-notation filter

```
(|(&(a)(b)(|(c)(d)))(&(e)(b)(|(c)(d))))
```

becomes this infix notation filter:

```
 (a&b&(c|d))|(e&b&(c|d))
```

And then use any normal boolean expression optimiser/simplifier, I'm lazy so I'll let [Wolfram do it](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28a%26b%26%28c%7Cd%29%29%7C%28e%26b%26%28c%7Cd%29%29).

Now fish out the simplest minimal form result, the [DNF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunctive_normal_form) or [CNF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_normal_form) forms are only `and` and `or` operations, these can be readily used as LDAP filters (anything without ⊻ "xor" is likely good). The *CNF* is clearly simpler here:

```
DNF   (a ∧ b ∧ c) ∨ (a ∧ b ∧ d) ∨ (b ∧ c ∧ e) ∨ (b ∧ d ∧ e)
CNF   (a ∨ e) ∧ b ∧ (c ∨ d)
```

("∧" is "and", "∨" is "or")

Turning it back into a prefix filter and substituting the symbols you get:

```
(& (| (cn=PATH*)(cn=MICR*) )
   (cn=*2013*)
   (| (cn=*_S1_*)(cn=*_1_*) )
)
```

There is one last trivial optimisation, you can merge some types of sub-string matches without using operators when they don't overlap:

```
(& (| (cn=PATH*2013*)(cn=MICR*2013*))
   (| (cn=*_S1_*)(cn=*_1_*))
)
```

If you need to do this programmatically for arbitrary filters you can readily find code to perform prefix/infix conversion, and boolean expression optimisation in PHP, these are common problems in parsers and expression evaluation.

I suspect you'll need to special-case merging terms with prefix/infix/suffix strings when you have zero or one of each, I'm not aware of a name for such a process. You'll need it to be aware of the LDAP `attribute=` syntax in any case.