# Boolean operations Optimization

Tags: c#

I had a tool that generated several Boolean values, something that looks like this:

```
(!(dcn.XdbDate != null)) && (dcn.XdaDate != null)
```

The longest is 1361 characters long. I need to copy these over to C# source files to be used in linq queries.

My question is first, does C# automatically optimize these operators? In the above example, would it be automatically converted to the below when compiled?

```
dcn.XdbDate == null && dcn.XdaDate != null
```

If not, is there some C# compiler features where I can write a program, feed it the non-optimized ones and get optimized ones?

Edit:

Most of the generated Boolean operations are in the form of

```
xxx1 = condition ? value11 : value12,
xxx2 = condition ? value21 : value22,
etc...
```

The problem is with the `condition` part being not optimized.

Comment: Which LINQ flavour are you talking about? C# does not optimize this. But an `IQueryable<T>` provider might.

Comment: I am using EF, to be used in LINQ to Entities

Comment: Then check the query plan to see how EF and/or SQL server optimized it.

Comment: I can't fathom any way that not making this optimization and performing an extra NOT on this expression as making any perceivable difference in the performance of your application.  You shouldn't *care* whether or not it makes such an optimization.  Focus on more important considerations that are going to have impacts that are more than just a few nanoseconds.

Comment: Even if EF does not perform that optimization, it will be made by SQL Server anyway.

Comment: If you know exactly where the code is, you can have a look at the disassembly using ildasm from the SDK.  If the number of instructions generated is the same for both expressions, then it is optimized.

Comment: Your best bet is probably to modify the tool so that it generates the expressions you want. Regardless, it's quite likely that either the C# compiler or the JIT compiler will optimize `!(x != null)` to `x == null`. But does it matter? Do you think these expressions are really a bottleneck in your program?

Comment: Thank you all for the comments. I guess I don't need to spend time on this, it's not really a bottleneck. I was just wondering if there was an easy way to convert mostly for readability specially when I saw quite a few ones 1300+ characters long.

Comment: If the issue is only readability, you're looking for a way to simplify boolean expressions (not at compile time, but right now). You can replace the expression `dcn.XdbDate != null` with `A` and use something like [Wolfram Alpha on it](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28!%28A%29%29+%26%26+%28A%29) as suggested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14902141/any-good-boolean-expression-simplifiers-out-there)

Comment: `(!(dcn.XdbDate != null)) && (dcn.XdaDate != null)` makes no sense.

The first half of the expression will compile the expression in the parenthesis first (operational precedence), so that logic is literally asking if the dcn.XdaDate is not null, then inverting it, than moving ahead with a short-circuit AND that will not even get to the second half of the expression if the first one returns false.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an easy answer.. but let's try anyway.

In a more "generic" approach you are asking how to know what is being/going to be optimized and what is not? - of course as a responsible developer you have to assume that nothing will be optimized for you and writing an optimized code is fully under your responsibility.
Having that said, we of course know that some things do get optimized automatically.

**Optimization may occur in 3 distinguished occasions:**

1. During the build of the Debug version.
2. During the build of the Release version.
3. By executing the NGEN utility on an already built file.

The optimizations can be described as an onion - the outer shell will always include the inner shells and will add something of its own.

So,

**What type of optimizations can occur in debug?**
Only optimizations that will not change the code-separations for the user who debug.
In example: `if(a==!true && a==false)`
`a==!true` is identical to `a==false` - so having just 1 of those is a good idea - but if such an optimization will take place the developer will not be able to step by step the expression as it could before the optimization - so such optimization will not occur in debug version.

However.. `a==!true` - only this autonomous part can be replaced to `a==false` underneath without breaking the expression separation - meaning it will be ok from the compiler point of view to replace: 
 `if(a==!true && a==false)` to a perhaps faster instructions set which actually represent
 `if(a==false && a==false)` as expression separation will not be hit and debugging or stepping into will not change.

**What type of optimizations can occur in release?**
If we get back to the same example - in release - the expression `if(a==!true && a==false)` can be optimized to `if(a==false)` as it is predefined that a release is not meant for debugging therefore the compiler has nothing to worry about when doing such an optimization.

**What type of optimization can occur in NGEN?**
This is an entirely different vertical...
NGEN can be made for debug or for release - meaning same rules apply just as before and this is actually being done by the JIT when you built the code. The NGEN Job is to optimize the code it finds to the native (current) machine CPU architecture. I will not cover it here - you can read all about it from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6t9t5wcf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

*Keep in mind: if an expression cannot be stepped into per the parts of it - it is already optimized.*